# How to get QTableView right clicked index

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview

The code below creates a single dialog with a `QTableView` view.
On left-click the `onLeftClick`function gets an QModelIndex `index`. 
This QModelIndex is used later to print the row and column numbers of the left-clicked cell.

How to get the `QModelIndex` index of the cell that was right-clicked?

[image]

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
app = QApplication([])


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.view = QTableView(self)
        self.view.setSelectionBehavior(QTableWidget.SelectRows)
        self.view.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.view.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.onRightClick)
        self.view.clicked.connect(self.onLeftClick)

        self.view.setModel(QStandardItemModel(4, 4))
        for each in [(row, col, QStandardItem('item %s_%s' % (row, col))) for row in range(4) for col in range(4)]:
            self.view.model().setItem(*each)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.view)
        self.resize(500, 250)
        self.show()

    def onRightClick(self, qPoint):
        sender = self.sender()
        for index in self.view.selectedIndexes():
            print 'onRightClick selected index.row: %s, selected index.column: %s' % (index.row(), index.column())

    def onLeftClick(self, index):
        print 'onClick index.row: %s, index.row: %s' % (index.row(), index.column())


dialog = Dialog()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `indexAt()` method of the `QAbstractScrollArea` (`QTableView`):

```
def onRightClick(self, qPoint):
    index = self.view.indexAt(qPoint)
    if index.isValid():
        print('onClick index.row: %s, index.col: %s' % (index.row(), index.column()))
```